# Ueshiba and Tomiki picture identification

Tags: aikido, history

Does anyone have any historical information about the following picture: when was it taken?  Who is in the background?  Where was it taken?  What was the occasion?

[image: Tomiki and Uesiba picture.]

Comment: A good tip for whenever you want more info about a picture: Drag it in Google Images. A yellow box will appear upon dragging it over the window, then Google can search the web for that exact picture ;)

Comment: Just look at the EXIF data ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the same picture at several websites.

According to [this blog](http://brunocarmenisjudoblog.com/1104/), the picture was taken in 1942 at the Kenkoku University. It also mentions "(Manchria)" but that's probably a typo for "Manchuria", the old name for north-east China which at that time was under Japanese control.

[Another website](http://tomikiaikido.blogspot.com/2010/09/tomiki-and-ueshiba-in-manchuria.html) mentions that the building in the background is Shimbuden Hall and describes the man standing on the right as "Hideo Oba".

[This page](http://blog.aikidojournal.com/2011/11/24/historical-photo-morihei-ueshiba-in-front-of-shimbuden-dojo-in-manchuria-1942) confirms both the year, location and identity of Hideo Oba. Since the people in both photo's have a similar position and are wearing the same outfit I'm guessing that both photo's are taken on the same day. If this is correct then the occasion was "the 10th anniversary of the founding of Manchukuo", which is the Japanese name for Manchuria. Between 1940 and 1942 Ueshiba visited Manchuria several times for teaching and demonstrations and it has been said that this was the last time he visited.